# Using Python 3 and Euclid’s algorithm to calculate the gcd of a list

Tags: python, greatest-common-divisor

I am trying to use Euclid’s algorithm to calculate the gcd of a list using Python 3. However, I get the error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'". I checked everywhere, but still can not find what's wrong with my code.
Here is my code,

```
# To get the gcd of a list
def gcd(numbers):
    m = numbers[0]
    for i in range(1, len(numbers)):
        m = gcd2(m, numbers[i])
    return m

# Use Euclid’s algorithm to calculate the gcd of two numbers
def gcd2(m, n):
    if m % n != 0:
        gcd2(n, m % n)
    else:
        return n

def main():
    str = [44, 6, 12, 24, 4, 18]
    print(gcd(str))

main()
```

Comment: At some point, `m` or `n` is `None` instead of a number.

Comment: If `if m % n != 0:` is True then you break out of the function with no `return` value. That means you get a `None` value for `m` from `m = gcd2(m, numbers[i])`

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a return statement on line 3 of gcd2. The updated function is below.

```
def gcd2(m, n):
    if m % n != 0:
        return gcd2(n, m % n)
    else:
        return n
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The code could be even better written as 
```if m %n == 0:  
    return n  
return gcd2(n, m % n)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def gcd2(m, n):
    if m % n != 0:
        gcd2(n, m % n)
    else:
        return n
```

In the `if` You aren’t returning anything, so it defaults to `None`. Add return there.

Comment: You posted his exact code, with the return that he already has. I think you misread something.

Comment: @Nathan - I’ve then written what needs to be changed.

Comment: That's a comment, not a solution.